# how to handle javascript callback return data in python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, callback

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET', '/Search?' + query, async);  

if (async) {  
 req.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                var response = null;
                try {
                      response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

                    } catch (e) {
                                 response = req.responseText;
                                 }
                     callback(response);
```

This callback function returns values to my python code (I am using GAE with python 2.7).

```
class KeywordSearchRPCHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        webapp2.RequestHandler.__init__(self)
        self.methods = RPCMethods()
    def get(self):
        func = None
        action = self.request.get('action')
        if action:
            if action[0] == '_':
                self.error(403) # access denied
                return
            else:
                func = getattr(self.methods, action, None)
        if not func:
            self.error(404) # file not found
            return

        else :
            args = ()
            while True:
                key = 'arg%d' % len(args)
                val = self.request.get(key)
                #print val
                if val:
                    args = (json.loads(val))
                else:
                    break
            result = func(*args)

            self.response.out.write(json.dumps(result))
```

This is the code that handles the callback function.

I get the error **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Could you please help me modify my code.  Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation: [Docs](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.RequestHandler)

`webapp2.RequestHandler.__init__(request=None, response=None)` is the signature.

So add request and response as parameters to your init and you should be fine.

Change `def __init__ (self)` to `def __init__(self, request=None, response=None)`. This will fix the bug.

And you probably want to call `super` properly instead of calling `__init__` on the class here:  `webapp2.RequestHandler.__init__(self)`

This should most likely be `super(KeywordSearchRPCHandler, self).__init__(request, response)` instead.

Comment: I am using PyScripter .  Could you please help me with making the PyScripter see the Google Appengine SDK so I can debug the code.  I am new to programming and I searched the web for an answer but couldn't find it.  Probably it is a silly question but I need to start debugging.

Comment: When I stopped calling the constructor altogether, it worked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The init handler:

```
class RPCHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """ Allows the functions defined in the RPCMethods class to be RPCed."""

    def __init__(self, request, response):

        super(RPCHandler, self).__init__(request, response)
        self.methods = RPCMethods()
```

But I do not understand your json.loads(val) in your GET, because you send a query string and not a json request.

Below is an example post, handling a json post:

```
def post(self):

    data = self.request.body
    args = loads(data)

    if 'action' not in args:
        self.error(405)  # access denied
        return

    func = args['action']

    if func[0] == '_':
        self.error(403)  # access denied
        return

    func = getattr(self.methods, func, None)
    if not func:
        self.error(404)  # file not found
        return

    # action handler aanroepen
    result = func(args)
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(result))
```

If you use a GET with a query string webapp2 will handle the request. From the docs:

```
# An iterable with all items in the MultiDict:
# [('check', 'a'), ('check', 'b'), ('name', 'Bob')]
self.request.GET.items()
```